Retopologizing Hard Surface Model - Panel Lines
I'm working on retopologizing a model I'm working on for 3D printing, and which I may use for some other things, as well (IE a high-poly model for baking). The original is kind of a mess of tris, quads, and ngons, and I want to get that cleaned up before I get too much further into things.
What would you recommend as the best way to handle panel lines? Some places aren't too bad because the panels on the original model follow the edge loops. However, then I get to places like this:

I've turned on the wireframe so you can see what's happening. There's several places where panel lines are crossing the edge loops at an angle. Others are parallel to the loop, but aren't actually on it. So it's really not possible to keep neat, evenly-spaced quads. How exactly do I handle this to keep nice topology and avoid ngons or triangles, while keeping good spacing on the edge loops without things getting too bunched up?.

Hi, Ambaryerno, SE sites really want to follow a format: ranked, definite answers to definite questions, searchable in the archive. This is 2 questions: one about retopology, and another about Solidify. Both are valid, but they need splitting up, so you're asking one at a time.  Please edit to do that, so we can reopen this question for you, expecting another.

Hi, Ambaryerno.. Thanks for splitting the question. I'm assuming this one is covered by the other 2, so doesn't need a re-open itself. Of course, call up here if I've misread that.

@RobinBetts This is a separate question. This is about how to break the topology up into panels, not the Solidify or Subsurface modifiers.

Okydoky.. sorry for the delay.
